# jQuery Validate – conditionally highlighting input parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a custom styled select for which I need to attach the error class to its wrapper so I'm doing this:

```
$('form').validate({
    ignore: [],
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr('name') === 'state') {
            error.insertAfter('.select-wrap');
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        if (element.type === 'select') {
            $(element).parent('.select-wrap').addClass('error');
        } else {
            $(element).addClass('error');
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        if (element.type === 'select') {
            $(element).parent('.select-wrap').removeClass('error');
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass('error');
        }
    }
});
```

That gets my error labels in the right places but it's still adding the error class to the select element, not its parent.

If I change `if (element.type === 'select')` to `if (element.attr('name') === 'select')` for the highlight/unhighlight functions, validate fails to fire at all. :?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that, when you say `element.type` it is returning `select-one` so your comparison `element.type === 'select'` is failing.

Instead you can use either `element.tagName === 'SELECT'` or `$(element).is('select')`

```
$('form').validate({
    ignore: [],
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.attr('name') === 'state') {
            error.insertAfter('.select-wrap');
            error.removeClass('error')
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        console.log(element, element.type, element.tagName)
        if ($(element).is('select')) {
            $(element).parent('.select-wrap').addClass('error');
        } else {
            $(element).addClass('error');
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        if ($(element).is('select')) {
            $(element).parent('.select-wrap').removeClass('error');
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass('error');
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g984mygp/)

[HTMLSelectElement.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/type)

> The HTMLSelectElement.type read-only property returns the form
>   control's type. The possible values are:
>
> - "select-multiple" if multiple values can be selected.
> - "select-one" if only one value can be selected.

Comment: Yes, it was the 'select-one' not matching that was the problem, thanks. :)